# How to kill a stuck query process in Apache IoTDB when time series data is large?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Considering the size of the time series, how may Apache IoTDB terminate the query process?

Is there a method to terminate the query process when it becomes stuck if a significant number of time series were returned from a query using Apache IoTDB? which would be comparable to the command "display process list." IoTDB provide any options to accomplish this?

Is there anyone who can solve this issue? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to passively waiting for query timeouts, Apache IoTDB also supports actively terminating queries by using "KILL QUERY ". "queryId" represents the specified query, so quotes need to be added when using it.

In order to get the "queryId" being executed, user can use the "show queries" command, which will display a list of all executing queries. If you want to terminate all queries, you can use `KILL ALL QUERIES`.